# SDK similar to SPen SDK but runs on every phone

Tags: android, canvas, samsung-mobile

Is there any SDK that is similar to the SPen SDK by Samsung but lets you draw with normal stylus (the SPen SDK  is meant for S Pen alone) ?

Comment: What types of styluses work depends on the touchscreen / stylus technology. You can't make others work by just using a different piece of software.